# Latex (XeTex) places equation parenthesis the wrong way

Tags: xetex, equations, brackets, unicode-math

I recently switched compilation of my tex document from pdflatex to xetex for reasons of typesetting occasional arabic text (the rest of document though is almost entirely in English).

However now I have the problem of ``misaligned'' equation parenthesis both next to the equation and in \eqrefs as visible here:
[image]

I switched to using fontspec, unicode-math and polyglossia packages to be able to compile with xetex.

I even tried redefining the format of the equation brackets, but nothing changed. Any Ideas what is happening here?

My document preamble looks like this:

```
 PACKAGES
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\small\itshape}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal} % flushright
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[norule]{footmisc} % no footnote rule [better if we use footrulewidth]
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
% FONT with xetex:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{Scheherazade}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\onehalfspacing

% SOME MATH (RE)NEWCOMMANDS
[...]
```

Comment: it looks like that you have the arabic language enabled. However, your code snippet is useless. Create a _small_ complete example which shows the behaviour.

Comment: In particular, please reduce the preamble to the minimal set of packages required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks David, my question refers to the same thing. Was able to solve it by redefining \maketag@@@.